# Is there a way to place image frames in Sketch 3?

Tags: images, sketch-app

In Indesign it is possible to place a rectangle frame (Rectangle Frame Tool) to fill it at a later time with an image. Does Sketch 3 have a way to place images at later time?

I can't find something like the rectangle frame tool and it seems impossible to easily crop an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Sketch is not InDesign

Sketch doesn't have the content box types that InDesign requires, it's just images and masks. Use a rectangle as your placeholder and convert it to a mask once the image is placed.

#### Step by step

1. Start with a rectangle
   [image: a beautiful grey rectangle]
2. Add your image
   [image: drop in your image]
3. Select both the image and rectangle and click Mask in the toolbar
   [image: mask objects button]
4. An image in your rectangle — imagine that!
   [image: cropped to perfection]

#### Behind the scenes

The mask button is actually just a shortcut. The actual mask process is to group the objects and select `Use as Mask` in the layers menu for the mask object. Everything you add to that group will be contained in the mask. Very similar to Illustrator's solution (as of the last time I used Illy, anyway).

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately not the same handy way as Indesign but it will work.

Comment: Images are definitely a second class citizen in Sketch. It's all about the UI template; the stuff that fills the template is best done elsewhere and dropped in as an optimized asset.

Comment: This is a model answer

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this, although it is not as robust as in inDesign.

Create a rectangle, and when you want to place an image inside of it, under "Fill" on the right side,click on the photos icon, and choose a photo to fill the rectangle.[image]